# "Copyright on" or "Copyright to"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

What is the difference between "Copyright on something" and "Copyright to something", if any?
Can I also say "I have rights on something" or only "I have rights to something" is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/):

> **copyright** (*in/on something*) if a person or an organization holds the copyright on a piece of writing, music, etc, they are the only people who have the legal right to publish, broadcast, perform it, etc, and other people must ask their permission to use it or any part of it.

Although it might be interesting to notice, [here](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=copyright%20on,copyright%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), that also the other expression is used.

Answer (score 1):

Both usages are fairly common. You could also hold the copyright in something.